# Dynamically creating ng-templates to show popover content using angular-ui-bootstrap

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui

The popover works if i hardcode template id as id="popover00.html"
But it doesnot work when the same id is generated from ng-repeat.It is looking for file on server.

**Popover Works:**

```
 <div  ng-repeat="(keyT, T) in Tdata track by $index"> 

   <div ng-repeat="(keyS,S) in Sdata track by $index" popover-trigger="mouseenter" uib-popover-template={{"'popover"+keyT+keyS+".html'"}} >
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="popover00.html">
      <div>
        This is an HTML <b>template</b><br>

      </div>
    </script>
   </div> 
 </div>
```

**Popover not working:**

```
 <div  ng-repeat="(keyT, T) in Tdata track by $index"> 

   <div ng-repeat="(keyS,S) in Sdata track by $index" popover-trigger="mouseenter" uib-popover-template={{"'popover"+keyT+keyS+".html'"}} >
    <script type="text/ng-template" id={{"popover"+keyT+keyS+".html"}}>
      <div>
        This is an HTML <b>template</b><br>

      </div>
    </script>
   </div> 
 </div>
```

Comment: Validate that keyT and keyS are what you expect in the "not working" example. Just place a {{keyT}} and {{keyS}} under the second div.

Comment: Working Example:
when i hardcode as id="popover00.html" ,the popover works.

Not working Exampe:
But when i ng-repeat, the id generated dynamically is same as above which is id="popover00.html",it do not work.On mouse enter it keeps looking for a file "http://localhost:5001/popover00.html"
KeyT and KeyS has values 0 in their first loop.

Comment: @NithishReddyJ I've tried to explain why your code isn't working, if you could provide more details of what problem you're trying to solve, perhaps in another question, we could provide some more help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `<script type="text/ng-template" id="templateUrl.html"></script>` provides a declarative way to insert a preloaded html content into `$templateCache` **at key equal to `id` attribute value**. Here is [the scource](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/script.js#L36) of the [`script`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/script) directive:

```
var scriptDirective = ['$templateCache', function($templateCache) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    terminal: true,
    compile: function(element, attr) {
      if (attr.type == 'text/ng-template') {
        var templateUrl = attr.id,
            text = element[0].text;

        $templateCache.put(templateUrl, text);
      }
    }
  };
}];
```

As you can see above the `attr.id` value is used at *compile* time. In your second example this value would be equal to string literal `'{{"popover"+keyT+keyS+".html"}}'`. That's the reason your second example doesn't work.